# @font-face onle affecting certain characters

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

Building a site using custom fonts. Got .ttf files from a designer.

css looks like this:

```
@font-face{
font-family:MenuFont;
src: url("http://www.website.com/assets/fontfile.ttf"); 
}

.divClass{font-family:MenuFont;}
```

I've tried with a couple different font files he gave me. One of them doesn't show up at all. Even more strangely, a couple of them only effect certain letters. For instance, plugging in one file makes only O's, R's C's and P's use the correct font. I checked and it's the same letters across browsers.

Looking in firebug, I can see the whole font, when I roll over the font file url, so my Url's are fine, and the browser is getting the font.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Generate the correct `font-face` code and all the needed fonts with FontSquirrel. See: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

You will get a more extended and compatible `font-face` declaration. Like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Meran';
    src: url('../fonts/meran-normal-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/meran-normal-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/meran-normal-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/meran-normal-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/meran-normal-webfont.svg#Meran') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Checked out font squirrel, it's telling me that about half of the font files I've been given are corrupt... Guess I should talk to my designer. Any idea what I should tell him to be most helpful? Could always just go the use images route...

Comment: Guess the fonts are just damaged. Maybe he can redownload them from the source or give you à direct link.